# How can I tell whether or not equipment is metal?

Tags: final-fantasy-4

I have just made it to Troia in search of the earth crystal, but I have been told that a dark elf stole it and hid it away with him in a magnetically charged cave. Because of this, metal equipment will render me immobile while in the cave.

The problem is, I have no idea what's metal and what isn't. Is Mythril metal or some kind of stone? Is a "rod" made of metal? How can I tell what's made of metal?

If there's no in-game way to tell what's made of metal, then what is the best non-metal equipment I can use for this cave that is available at this point in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, most weapons that aren't metal will explicitly say so in their name. For instance, Cid can freely use the **Wooden Hammer**, but his other mallets won't be usable. The same is true of the **Ancient Sword** for Cecil, though if you've sold or missed that, he'll need to use a Bow, Staff, or one of the elemental 'Shard' weapons available in Troia. Additionally, Yangs claws are all considered non-metal, as are all Bows/Arrows, Rods, and Staves that don't explicitly claim to be metal. (Mythril is considered metal).

Shields are all considered Metal, as are Iron and Silver rings. (Use Ruby Rings).

For Armor, there are light/leather options available in the nearest town, but in general, the names should clue you in; the Kenpo Gi, Feathered Hat, Headband, Gaia Gear, Bard's Tunic, etc. are all solid options.

Additionally, all Metallic equipment is flagged [on the Wiki here, if you need to double check.](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_IV_DS_Weapons) ([Armor here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_IV_DS_Armor).)

Comment: I don't think Cecil can equip bows :(

Comment: Depends on the game version. He could in the original 16 bit version. The DS/Mobile remake, it was removed because [reasons?].